# Write output file without exiting

Tags: gnuplot

How do I make an output of my graph without using 'exit'??
It makes me crazy because when the sizes go wrong, I have to do it from the start again. 
I did all the stuff like set term pdf and all that. Please tell me what can I do.

Answer (score 6):

to flush the buffer to the file you need to put a `set output` after issuing the `plot` or `splot` command(s).

example:

```
set term pdf
set output 'test.pdf'
plot sin(x)
set output
```

[Here](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-840007.6) is a FAQ answer to your problem

Comment: I mean, after set term pdf, set output 'file route here', plot "whatever", what do I need to do?

Comment: add an empty `set output` as I wrote above, did you try? This will flush the buffer to the file and close the gnuplot access to that file

Comment: oh!! That's great.